# git repo with submodules checkout fails in teamcity with error 'repo not found'

Tags: git, teamcity

Iam trying to checkout a repo which has git submodules, Teamcity throws an error saying repo not found

Iam trying to run teamcity build against development branch, which is present even in submodules, the ssh key configured can access both main repo and submodule repos

This is my .gitmodules file

```
[submodule "module1"]
    path = module1
    url = ssh://git@origin.company-url/module1.git
[submodule "module2"]
    path = module2
    url = ssh://git@origin.company-url/module2.git
```

[image: Teamcity build log]

Couldn't find any information online with this issue

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Hey, have exactly the same poblem. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @PavloYakovenko Teamcity has an option to checkout git repo with submodules, use it.

Create a step in your pipeline, which checkouts the submodules, refer this to checkout submodules
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update